# Why is string.find() only return true if it finds them in the first word?

Tags: c++, string, find, command-line-arguments

```
if(!next.find("+")){//////////////////////searching for +
for(int j=0;j<itemSize;j++){
if(!addItem[j].find(next)){
cout << addItem[j] << endl;//////why doesn't this work for multible words???
}
}
}
if(!next.find("@")){//////////////////////searching for @
    for(int j=0;j<itemSize;j++){
    if(!addItem[j].find(next)){
    cout << addItem[j] << endl;//why doesn't this work for multiple words???
    }
    }
    }
```

Why is my .find() for @ and + only return true if it finds them in the first word? I'm trying to search the whole string, and cout the whole string if it finds it.

This is a command line argument program;
If my todo.txt contains:
"dog"
"cat"
"bird +animal"
"+animal"
without the "".

If I use .find() to search for +animal, only the last element prints. Im trying for "bird +animal" and "+animal" to print.  Whats wrong?

full code::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    vector<string> addItem;
int numLines =0;
ifstream inDo("todo.txt");
string input;
while(getline(inDo, input)){////////////to get number of lines
    numLines++;
    addItem.push_back(input);
}
remove("todo.txt");
ofstream todo("todo.txt", std::fstream::app);
for(int i=0; i<argc; i++){
    string line = argv[i];
    if(!line.find("add")){/////////////////////adds to the list
        addItem.push_back(argv[i+1]);
        cout << addItem.back() << " - added on line " << numLines+1 << endl;
    }
    if(!line.find("clear")){////////////////////////////clears the list
        while(!addItem.empty()){
            addItem.pop_back();
        }
        cout << "List Has Been Cleared."<< endl;
    }
    if(!line.find("Do")){////////////////////to remove items from list
        if(i+2==argc){
            int taskNum = atof(argv[i+1]);
            cout << addItem[taskNum-1] << " has been completed << endl;
            addItem.erase(addItem.begin()+(taskNum-1));
        }
        else{
        cout << "Incorrect format, please retry with 'do #'" << endl;
        }
    }
    if(!line.find("ls")){/////////////////////////prints the list
        if(i+1==argc){
            int count=0;
            int listSize=addItem.size();
            while(count < listSize){
                cout << count+1 << " " << addItem[count] << endl;
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(i+2==argc){/////////////for searching for a certain word
            int itemSize=addItem.size();
            string next = argv[i+1];
            for(int a=0;a<itemSize;a++){
                if(!addItem[a].find(next)){
                    cout << addItem[a] << endl;
                }
            }
            if(!next.find("+")){/////////////searching for +
                for(int j=0;j<itemSize;j++){
                    if(!addItem[j].find(next)){
                        cout << addItem[j] << endl;
                                                    ///doesn't work!!
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!next.find("@")){//////////////////////searching for @
                for(int j=0;j<itemSize;j++){
                    if(!addItem[j].find(next)){
                        cout << addItem[j] << endl;
                                                      //dosen't work!!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
vector<string> temp;////////////////////reverse the vector order    
while(!addItem.empty()){
    temp.push_back(addItem.back());
    addItem.pop_back();
}
while(!temp.empty()){////////////////////send to file
    todo << temp.back() << "\n";
    temp.pop_back();
}
todo.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thats a looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooot of code. Please provide a simple example of your problem.

Comment: @user3092909 It's not possible that this *entire* thing is "the problematic part".

Comment: sorry, i moved the part i think is wrong to the top block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `string::find` doesn't return a `bool` but an `std::size_t`, indicating the position of the found substring. Thus, if your substring is located at the beginning of the string, this function will return `0`, which is considered false in a context where a logical expression is needed. If the string is not found, or if it is found at a location different from 0, it will return a non-zero value (`string::npos` or the location), which is then considered true.

So, `if (!list.find("whatever"))` is not the right way to check for the string not having been found. `if (list.find("whatever") == std::string::npos)` is.

Comment: @user3092909 In the string `+animals`, the character `'+'` is at position 0. [Proof](http://ideone.com/YOAJV0).

Comment: works perfect, Thank You so much! I still don't understand why mine didn't work, but o well, I'll just do it like this for now on.